# Is there a ratio faker for bittorrent?

Tags: software-recommendation, bittorrent

It might be a bit unethical question, but I am in need of a ratio faker for Bittorrent that works on Ubuntu. Which tool can you recommend?

Comment: Seems people really don't like this question. I can't really find anything wrong with it. Those down-voting wish to comment on the subject?

Comment: yeah, the question should be closed because if you want to use bittorrent, you must share what you get, so "faking" it is unethical, eh?

Comment: **Given the large volume of discussion regarding this I encourage all those who believe this should be closed on grounds of ethics to open a meta question for discussion.** Comments are not designed to field meta discussions and topics of policy

Comment: [Discussion opened on meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1804/10068), but not suggesting to close. You are invited to disagree. :) Or to agree, of course.

Comment: May I ask the purpose of this tool you want, Is this for testing purposes? Maybe edit your question to include a sample use.

Comment: -1 because fakes have personally effected me in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having searched the net for a long time, I come to the conclusion that there is no satisfying solution available. And considering the discussions here and at Meta, that probably is a good thing.

Answer (score 11):

After searching a bit I came across [RatioMaster.NET 0.42](http://ratiomaster.net/) that claims to work under Linux with `mono 2.6.3` and hardcoded support for torrent clients uTorrent, BitComet, Azureus, ABC, BitLord, BTuga, BitTornado, Burst, BitTyrant, BitSpirit. So this does not include `transmission` or `deluge` but some of these do work native under Linux or work with `wine`.

<sub>Did not test that program... my ratio on private trackers is more then sufficient ;)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

- [Joal](https://github.com/anthonyraymond/joal/releases): a command line tool (headless mode or optional webui).
- [Joal-Desktop](https://github.com/anthonyraymond/joal/releases): The above tool embedded in a desktop app.

These are tools i built some time ago. They are java coded, so you can run it on every OS as long as java is installed. It is also Docker ready if you want to.

See the README for documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Install Azureus and use Greedytorrent with WINE. Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just used https://github.com/MisterDaneel/Ratio.py and it works very well.
The script is using Python (I prefer Python and C / C++ over C# / .NET and Java).

My ratio changed from 1 to more than 100 in a few seconds by faking more than 1 terabyte data upload because I had set the upload variable in the file configuration.json to 100000 (kB/s) which was too much :D

It is better not to cheat but in my case, I did not find any torrent where there was a lot of leechers, it took too long to increase my ratio (ratio only increased from 0.1 in a day on most popular torrents).

Be careful if you fake your ratio, I read it can be detected and you could get banned: https://www.reddit.com/r/trackers/comments/4v5iqa/ratio_cheating_why_is_it_so_easy_and_what_can_be/